# Wick power of standard normal random variable equals Hermite polynomial.

Tags: probability-theory, hermite-polynomials, gaussian

> Let $\xi$ be a standard normal random variable, then **it's clear
>   that** :
>
> $$:\xi^n:=h_n(\xi)$$ where $h_n$ is the $n$-th Hermite polynomial.

I understand that $:\xi^n:$ is the orthogonal projection of $\xi^n$ in the $n$-th homogeneous chaos, and that the latter is spanned by the $n$-th hermite polynomial $h_n(\xi)$. Still, I am not able to see why the equality must hold, (does this hold up to a multiplicative constant?)

I mean, does this follow immediately from the definitions?  Because saying that an element belongs to the span of some vector, is not the same as saying that it equals this vector.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Wick product $\mathpunct: \xi_1 \dots \xi_n \mathpunct:$ coincides on any Gaussian Hilbert space containing $\xi_1, \dots, \xi_n$, it is enough to consider the Wick power $\mathpunct: \xi^n \mathpunct:$ on the Gaussian Hilbert space given by the span of $\xi$.

In particular, $H^{\mathpunct: n \mathpunct:}$ is one-dimensional and is spanned by $h_n(\xi)$. Therefore
$$\mathpunct{:}\xi^n \mathpunct{:} = \pi_n(\xi^n) = \lambda h_n(\xi)$$
a.s. for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

To identify $\lambda$, notice that by standard properties of orthogonal projections
$$\langle \mathpunct: \xi^n \mathpunct:, h_n(\xi) \rangle = \langle \xi^n, h_n(\xi) \rangle$$

Now since $\xi^n \in \bigoplus_{j=0}^n H^{\mathpunct: j \mathpunct:}$, we have the decomposition $\xi^n = \sum_{j=0}^n \langle \xi^n, h_j(\xi) \rangle h_j(\xi)$. Since the $n$-th order coefficients must match, we see that $\langle \xi^n, h_n(\xi) \rangle = 1$. Therefore
$$\lambda = \langle \mathpunct: \xi^n \mathpunct:, h_n(\xi) \rangle = \langle \xi^n, h_n(\xi) \rangle = 1$$

Comment: I'll have to offer you a beer man after all the help you've given to me! regarding the last part, yes, I was actually thinking about the one dimensional  case, the one in example 3.18 of Svante's book

Comment: I'm happy to help! It's also nice to go back and check my understanding of these things :) If you are interested in example $3.18$ in Svante's book then I have to be a bit more careful. An annoying subtlety is that he gets my formula for the Hermite polynomials from this result so that going by his presentation, my argument is circular (actually my argument is really the thing he suggests to see that that example generalises out of the one dimensional case). I'm writing an edit now.

Comment: hey rhys I am not entirely sure that I understand what follows the phrase " by the a.s. equality, since $\xi$ is Gaussian..." do you mind explaining it?

Comment: Sure! The idea is that rephrasing the claim "$h_n(\xi(\omega)) = p_n(\xi(\omega))$ for almost all $\omega \in \Omega$" in terms of the law of $\xi$, you get that $h_n(x) = p_n(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus N$ where $N$ is a null set for the standard Gaussian measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Since the standard Gaussian measure has a strictly positive density, $N$ is also a null set for the Lebesgue measure which implies that $h_n(x) = p_n(x)$ for almost all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure).

Comment: Now's everything clear! Thanks! Just as a curiosity, how long have you been working on this subjects? Are you doing a PhD in mathematics?

Comment: I'm a 2nd year maths PhD student. Wick products/Chaos expansions arise naturally in my field (singular SPDEs) since we need to renormalise certain objects. It's been about a year and a half since I first learnt this stuff I guess.

Comment: Well that's good news, I thought I was already in "disadvantage" or somehow "late". Even though I am doing a PhD in statistics my main objective is to work with SDE's but honestly all this stuff is new to me

Comment: @RScrlli Potentially more reassuring is that even then I am capable of badly messing up these things. My previous answer was garbage (I must have made a typo whilst writing it that lead me to write that $p_n = \lambda h_n$ and also that $p_n = h_n$ a.s. It's not very hard to see that $\lambda = 1$ from those assumptions but those assumptions are from a typo that included what was to be proven). Hopefully my edit is finally correct; the argument is much simpler now anyway.